# Is it possible to implement/override an abstract method with reflection?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a question about Reflection, but the motivation is from using Spring Framework.

Consider [this](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/projectionreflectiontest/src) project, which is a sort of Minimum Working Example version of a deployed project.

In the `ProjectionResourceProcessorConfig` class, I have an `entityProjectionResourceProcessor` method for every projection, and every entity in the database have a few projections. That's about 60 methods.

I don't want to keep this up because of the obvious maintenance disadvantage. I want to use Reflection in order to automatically register one bean for every projection class.

The `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` method in the `ProjectionResourceProcessorConfig` class shows that I can get the list of classes I want to use to register one bean for each and shows how to register a bean programatically.

However, because I need to use the `ProjectionResourceProcessor` class, I need to override the `getEntityClass` method. I haven't been able to find a way to do that programatically. That's why I've declared the inner class. It shows the programatic bean registration working, but it falls in the same issue as requiring a piece of code for every bean.

Apart from reflection, I tried to use the `setMethodOverrides` method of the `RootBeanDefinition` class to override that method, but I couldn't manage to understand how to use that method. Google couldn't find any documentation or usage example (except for a vaguely related Chinese post with copies on several different websites).

I also tried to use the `MethodReplacer` class but I haven't found how to use it with annotation driven configuration.

I also tried to replace the `getEntityClass` method by a variable and replace the variable's value by reflection, but apparently when the variable is read the value that was set in the super class is the one that is retrieved.

To test the project, run the tests at `DemoApplicationTests`. It will print the projection of some entities. If they have links, it's working.

Is it possible to do what I want? If it is, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot add, remove or override a method using reflection.  You might be able to do what you are trying to do using dynamic proxies, but I think there ought to be a simpler way to structure your code that avoids the *need* to do this.

Comment: @StephenC Regarding code restructure, there's a chance, but I think it depends on Spring. Regarding dynamic proxies, that's something I was unaware of. I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use Spring to instantiate everything.  And if you are having to write lots of cookie cutter code so so that Spring can instantiate the beans, maybe you should look at an alternative way.